# What is the difference between collaboration diagram and communication diagram in UML?

Tags: uml, collaboration-diagram, communication-diagram

What is the difference between collaboration diagram and communication diagram in UML? Are they the same diagram?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Sequence & Communication Diagram (UML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470813/difference-between-sequence-communication-diagram-uml)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are the same. This is just a name change. Collaboration diagrams was the name given to communication diagrams in previous versions of the UML standard

Comment: called as collaboration diagram in UML 1.X

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand collaboration is what needs what to work. And communication is what objects will be messaging other objects. They probably in most cases end up being quite similar because in order to collaborate they need to communicate. So the two would mostly be the same but different here and there.

Answer (score 0):

A communication diagram in the Unified Modeling Language (UML) 2.0, is a simplified version of the UML 1.x collaboration diagram.

They are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Collaboration Diagram is different from Communication Diagram. Collaboration Diagram show structure for communication/behavior.
The structure can be used for communication diagrams. For example, take a deployment diagram. It has communication paths such as http, amqp etc. On this communication path many business "messages" such as getEmpInfo etc can be passed. So, the communication path in deployment diagram is used by many communications/collaboration diagrams.
In case of collaboration diagram, the communication path is called connector/link/Message pathway and is generally not at infrastructure level. It is at component/class/business level.